# How to know user for query in Gremlin Console

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server

I can see following query fired in my gremlin-server.log.

25349979 [gremlin-server-exec-5] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.AbstractEvalOpProcessor  - Exception processing a script on request [RequestMessage{, requestId=71fe930a-92a1-4e53-a6e3-aca5f072fd74, op='eval', processor='', args={gremlin=g.V().drop();, userAgent=Gremlin Console/3.4.8, batchSize=64}}].

Would want to know, if there is any way to identify the user / time / console ip address from where query is was fired.

Thanks,
Atul.

Answer (score 1):

If you've enabled authentication then those features of a request should be available. You would need to look at the `enableAuditLog` [setting](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_configuring_2) for the server to get the output to the log.